# typescript how to reuse type in this case?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Test {
  name: "abcd" | "efgh" | "ijkl";
}

interface Human {
  name: "abcd" | "efgh" | "ijkl"
}
```

I want to reuse Test.name's type with Human.name, But how to? any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract names to a union type

```
type NameTypes = "abcd" | "efgh" | "ijkl";

interface Test {
  name: NameTypes;
}

interface Human {
  name: NameTypes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work

```
interface Test {
  name: "abcd" | "efgh" | "ijkl";
}

interface Human extends Test {

}
```